# How do I set default values in afform?

Tags: angular, formbuilder

I'm working on my first afform extension.

I've built a form, which works! I can submit values and create a contact.

However, I can't figure out how to pre-populate with default values. This is pretty important for the application. I've tried a number of things but none of them seem to work (not even the 'defn` one which came from a published example). Any suggestions? Note: I don't want to populate the form with the values from an existing contact. I need to insert new values into the form so when submitted, it creates a new contact.

```
 <af-form ctrl="modelListCtrl">
        <af-entity type="Contact" name="member" label="Member" />
        <div af-fieldset="member">
          <af-field name="first_name" ng-init="first_name = 'Betty'" />
          <af-field name="last_name" value="Smith" />
          <af-field name="do_not_email" defn="{type: 'checkbox', default: 1}" />
        </div>                                             
        <button ng-click="modelListCtrl.submit()">Submit</button>                                                                                              
  </af-form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Afform is still in beta so I expect this functionality to improve further, but currently it does support passing in an id via the url. It keys off the `af-entity` name property. So if you visit your form and add `?member=123` to the end of the url string it should load contact id 123 as the "Member". In that case it will update instead of creating a new contact.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I was hoping to set a value that does not come from the database - in other words, I want the form to submit a new contact, but I want the first and last names to be pre-populated on the form. Maybe not possible yet.